# How can i move the build agent to azure from my local docker image?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, containers

I built a container as per microsoft instructions here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

However this runs on my local machine , how can i move this to Azure? Im new to containers so not sure how this can be done

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are already have an images and from that images you build a local container(on your linux/Ubuntu Machine)

You can build the Azure Container instance(ACI) using the existing image in your local;

**Step 1**: For me, I pulled an image ie `nginx`  from  docker hub on my local machine(You can build your own images using YMAL files as well).

**`docker pull nginx`**

[image]

**Step 2**: Now Login in your azure subscription using below command

**`az login`**

**Step 3** : Create a Azure container registry(ACR).

**`az acr create -g "your resource groupname" -n "TestMyAcr90" --sku Basic --admin-enabled true`**

[image]

**Step 4** : Now login to you azure container registry: (you can get the user name and password for login from your azure container registry->AccessKey)

**`docker login testmyacr90.azurecr.io`**

[image]
[image]

**Step 5** : You need to tag the local images.

**`docker tag 605c77e624dd testmyacr90.azurecr.io/my_nginx`**

(where `605c77e624dd`  is IMAGE ID of nginx)

[image]

**Step 6** : use Docker push the images in Azure Container Registry(ACR)

**`docker push testmyacr90.azurecr.io/my_nginx`**

[image]

**Step 7** : Now you can create the Container Instance using the Container repositry.

**`az container create --resource-group` resourcegrouname`--name mycontainer90 --image testmyacr90.azurecr.io/my_nginx:latest --cpu 1 --memory 1 --registry-login-server testmyacr90.azurecr.io --registry-username TestMyAcr90 --registry-password` registrypassword `--dns-name-label testnginx5 --ports 80`**

**Note : you can name your own ACR,ACI and Dns-label-name**

[image]
[image]
[image]